# Shorter Screws for Hardie Board

Tags: screws, cement-board

The floating (unattached to subfloor) hearth I am building for my wood stove is going to be constructed in this order:

1. 1/2 plywood
2. Layer of thinset
3. 1/4 Hardie board
4. Thinset
5. Tiles

The recommended screws for concrete board are too long at 1 1/4", because they will penetrate the floor underneath, and I am trying to avoid that at all costs.  1/2 of plywood, plus the hardie board and thinset is still not 1 1/4".

My alternative is to use these really nice shorter 1" wood screws (see link).  They are exterior corrosion-resistant grade, and have the little ridges underneath the screwhead, but they are not wafer head style.

Is this a bad idea to use these shorter screws, even though they will penetrate the entire piece of plywood?  They are corrosion resistant, so it feels like they should work, and I may just space them a little bit tighter than specification.  This is a floor level application, not vertical/wall, so it seems like the extra 1/4" doesn't matter..

Product Guide:
https://bigtimberfasteners.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/BTX-Sell-Sheet.pdf

Comment: Why is it that the entire hearth will be floating? I'm not challenging you on that, I'm curious what that buys you.

Comment: We just laid new floor across the entire living room.  I got convinced to put the hearth over the top and avoid screws or glue to preserve the flooring underneath.  We are putting the orientation at 90 to the wall instead of the more common diagonal corner placement (has to do with existing windows and space for wood).  Not sure if we are overthinking it, but wanted to leave option open so if hearth was moved or stove reoriented, the matching floor was already underneath.

Comment: I would suggest that after a year or two, the flooring hidden by the hearth will no longer be a match for the flooring that's currently visible. The UV rays change the color of finishes in your house just like it changes the color of the finish on your body, but in the opposite direction. House materials fade while our skin darkens. i.e. that part of the logic isn't buying you anything.

Comment: We changed our minds.  We pulled the flooring and fastened the Hardie board to the subfloor.  Thanks!  Your opinion helped, along with others.